# how to interpret 8 neighbors as follows

Tags: matlab, connected-components

i would like to find 8 neighbors. In an algorithm it is written as

```
int Nx[] = {-1, 1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 1,  1}; //8-neighbors
int Ny[] = {0, 0, -1, 1,  1, -1, 1, -1};
```

how 3*3 matrix is interpreted like this?

Comment: what does it mean interpret? What kind of algorithm do you mean?

Comment: in an implementation of moore neighbourhood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are relative x- and y- coordinates. It becomes clearer if you convert this to coordinate pairs:

```
 x  y     neighbour
----------------------
-1  0     left
 1  0     right
 0 -1     bottom
 0  1     top
-1  1     left-top
-1 -1     left-bottom
 1  1     right-top
 1 -1     right-bottom
```